# how to display bindingresult errors on JSP page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a requirement to display errors on JSP page.

User enters credentials in login screen and it goes to logincontroller once login success user will be redirected to AccountsummaryController it has some backend calls to fetch data and display those data on landing page that is AccountSummary page. There could be possibility that some of the data may not be fetched for various reasons. I want those errors to be passed to the JSP page to show on landing page after successful login. Below is the code snippet of controller method in accountsummary controller. Also I am planning to have some validations in modelattribute i.e. stmtForm. I hope form errors also goes as part of the result.

```
@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET }, value = "stmtSummary")
    public ModelAndView getStatementSummary(@ModelAttribute("stmtForm") StatementForm stmtForm, BindingResult result, ModelMap modelMap,  HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

    result.addError(new ObjectError("error1","unable to get account number"));
    result.addError(new ObjectError("error2","unable to get routing number"));
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        System.out.println("Total errors are >>>>"+result.getErrorCount());  // *this is getting printed as 2*
    }
}
```

Here is the tag I am using in JSP page.

```
<form:errors path="*"/>
```

I am not able to display errors on the UI. I am not able to find the what is wrong here. Please help

Comment: Check whether your `<form:errors>` tag is within `<form:form>` tag and in **getStatementSummary method**, place *BindingResult* immediately after *stmtForm* argument.

Comment: Also *value* attribute in RequestMapping should be **"/stmtSummary"**

Comment: @DhavalSimaria yes, form:errors tag is within <form:form>.  even the BindingResult placed immediately after stmtForm argument.  also the request mapping  "stmtSummary" is also reachable when it redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Since you havent posted model class or form, it is difficult to understand whether you have error1 or error2 as attribute in your StatementForm Bean. You are trying to show custom business errors with the spring mvc bindingResult. There are two options to do that:

1. Use custom errorObject and add it in modelMap and check that in jsp.
2. For using it with BindingResult, use:

   ```
   result.rejectValue("property", "unable to get account number"); 
    //or
   result.reject("unable to get account number");
   ```